# change cursor over a pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, mouseenter, mousehover

i was trying to implemet an image button in winforms application as i can ...easy when using asp.net 
the problem seem to be(i suspect) that when the mouse is over the image inside the picturebox 
it is not responding or not triggering the mouseEnter event

it looks like if i had a picture that is smaller than the pictureBox Size it will accept the reason to trigger the event but over the image within the pictureBox it would Not  ?

the trick was to set pictureBox to sizeMode=zoom. then do 2 things when the mouse is over the "imageButton" : change the size of PictureBox a little larger + change cursor to hand

so i will get a kind of mouse over effect as i could with asp.net

did anyone have that problem ?
at first i tried mouseHover, then i thought  enter would do better as it only requiers the mouse to pass the borders of the picture box... both enter and hover events did not work for me ...

**Edit :**

the event does trigger , i can see that if i initially set sizemode to CenterImage and inside the event 
i ask for sizemode=zoom, so the effect dose occur ..but cursor.current=Cursors.Hand will not change.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

seem like i should have known better how to use Cursors class .

```
cursor=Cursors.hand;
```

rather than

```
cursor.current=Cursors.hand;
```

that was embarrassing ..

Answer (score 1):

only add MouseMove event on pictureBox and set a Cursor for this

```js
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for you code to be easier understood by the rest.